# Marker icon images not displaying in Leaflet.StyleEditor

Tags: style, image, markers, icon

While using Leaftlet.StyleEditor plugin, I cannot change the marker icon as the available icon images are not displayed. I tried the Demo(https://dwilhelm89.github.io/Leaflet.StyleEditor/) from the plugin's documentation, same issue exists. Attached is the screenshot from the demo.
[image]